# In Android, populate SQLite DB table from String Arrays

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to populate an Android `SQLIte` database table using String Arrays. I've got arrays that look like this:

```
idStrArray = "1, 2, 3, 4"
titleStrArray = "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
descrStrArray = "Descr 1", "Descr 2", "Descr 3", "Descr 4"
locationStrArray = "Location 1", "Location 2", "Location 3", "Location 4"
```

And I can't figure out how to write a method in the DBAdapter Class that would populate a DB Table using the arrays like this:

```
ID  TITLE  DESCR  LOCATION
1  title1  descr1 location1
2  title2  descr2 location2
3  title3  descr3 location3
4  title4  descr4 location4
```

I tried this in the Adapter Class:

```
    DBAdapter Class:

public long AddStrArraysToDB(String[] calTitleStrArray, String[] calDescrStrArray, String[]     calLocationStrArray){
    try{

        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        cv = new ContentValues();

        //--- title
        for(int i=0;i<calTitleStrArray.length;i++){
            cv.put(KEY_EVENT_TITLE, calTitleStrArray[i]);
            mDb.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        //--- end title

        //--- descr
        for(int i=0;i<calDescrStrArray.length;i++){
            cv.put(KEY_EVENT_DESCR, calDescrStrArray[i]);
            mDb.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        //--- end descr

        //--- location
        for(int i=0;i<calLocationStrArray.length;i++){
            cv.put(KEY_EVENT_LOCATION, calLocationStrArray[i]);
            mDb.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        //--- end location

        mDb.close();



    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("Error in phone contact insertion", ex.toString());
    }//--- END Try
    return mDb.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);

}
```

and then tried calling this method in the MainActivity like this:

```
    Main Activity:

Cal27Adapter addData = new Cal27Adapter(Cal27Main.this);
            addData.open();
            addData.AddStrArraysToDB    (calTitleStrArray,calDescrStrArray,calLocationStrArray);
            addData.close();
```

Doing this throws an exception. Any ideas how I can write a method in the Adapter class that would add the String Arrays as columns to my DB table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a single loop, and fill all fields for each record, i.e.

```
    for(int i=0; i < calTitleStrArray.length ; i++){
        cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_EVENT_TITLE, calTitleStrArray[i]);
        cv.put(KEY_EVENT_DESCR, calDescrStrArray[i]);
        cv.put(KEY_EVENT_LOCATION, calLocationStrArray[i]);
        mDb.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
```

This assumes that all the arrays have the same length (which is reasonable for this case).